# Passing model data from view back to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, actionlink

I want to know if this is possible using the Html.ActionLink().

In conroller:
I have queried my database and passed that data to the view.

In view:
I have used that data to fill inputs, labels, etc... However I want to reduce the number of query hits by passing the same data back to the controller, so it can be used on another view. Can this be done by passing the Model back to the controller using Html.ActionLink()?

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Account(int id, int? activelink, CombineModel CombineModel)
{
FetchLookupTables(CombineModel.Dwelling);

        if (CombineModel == null)
        {
            return new FileNotFoundResult { Message = "No Account found for id " + id.ToString() };
        }
        else if (CombineModel.Dwelling == null)
        {
            CombineModel = new CombineModel()
            {
                Owner = OwnerDB.FindOne(GetUserId(), id),
                Dwelling = DwellingDB.FindOne(GetUserId(), id),
                Image = ImageDB.FindOne(GetUserId(), id)
            };
            return View(CombineModel);
        }
        else
        {
            return View(CombineModel);
        }
}
```

View:

```
@model  Apartment.Models.CombineModel

@{
    string[] names = {"Details", "Listings", "Profile"};
}
<ul>                
        @for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            <li>@Html.ActionLink(names[i],"Account", new { id = Model.Owner.ID, activelink = i, CombineModel = Model}, null)</li>
        } 
</ul>
```

Comment: Can you post the relevant code?

Comment: @ShaneAndrade Posted relevant code.

Comment: May need to change to : `@Html.ActionLink(names[i],"Account", new { @id = Model.Owner.ID, @activelink = i, @CombineModel = Model}, null)`

Comment: @afzalulh Negative... Null reference at FetchLookupTables(CombineModel.Dwelling)

Comment: Html.ActionLink use HTTP GET to send the data to the server. You may want to store what you want to send to the controller (redundant data) as a javascript object in the view and use Ajax.ActionLink to do the posting.

Comment: Or consider passing Model.ID rather than Model itself.

Comment: In MVC pattern's application to web there should be no direct flow of information from view to controllers. Instead it should happen through user (which, usually will be a web-browser).